# What cause MAPI_E_TABLE_TOO_BIG in HrQueryAllRows method?

Tags: c++, outlook, mapi

I'm applying a set of PR_ANR restriction to my MAPI table(IMAPITable).The goal for this query is to match input strings with accounts in GAL.

The error raised only when the input string is "x" or "s".
hResult return hex value 80040403. Looking into MAPICode.h ,it says MAPI_E_TABLE_TOO_BIG.

But in fact, I've tried to type these two words (separately) into the Outlook GAL contact search box, and it has shown limited results.(54 results for s, 0 for x)
It made me really confused about the returned table being too big.

Below is my c++ code(simplified):

```
//SRestriction setup
    SRestriction pRestop = {};
    SRestriction pPropRes[3] = {};
    SPropValue sPropValue[2] = {};
    //RES_AND
    //  RES_PROP(1)
    //  RES_PROP(2)

    //RES_AND
    pRestop.rt = RES_AND;
    pRestop.res.resAnd.cRes = 3;
    pRestop.res.resAnd.lpRes = &pPropRes[0];
    //RES_Property -> First
    pPropRes[0].rt = RES_PROPERTY;
    pPropRes[0].res.resProperty.ulPropTag = PR_ANR_W;
    sPropValue[0].ulPropTag = PR_DISPLAY_NAME_W;
    sPropValue[0].Value.lpszW = tmp1; //first string
    pPropRes[0].res.resProperty.lpProp = &sPropValue[0];
    //RES_Property -> Second
    pPropRes[1].rt = RES_PROPERTY;
    pPropRes[1].res.resProperty.ulPropTag = PR_ANR_W;
    sPropValue[1].ulPropTag = PR_DISPLAY_NAME_W;
    sPropValue[1].Value.lpszW = tmp2; //second string
    pPropRes[1].res.resProperty.lpProp = &sPropValue[1];
    //tmp1 can be equal to tmp2

    enum
    {
        accPR_DISPLAY_NAME_W,
        accPR_SMTP_ADDRESS_W,
        accNUM_COLS
    };

    static SizedSPropTagArray(accNUM_COLS, accCols) = {
        accNUM_COLS, PR_DISPLAY_NAME_W, PROP_TAG(PT_UNICODE, 0x39FE)};

    // Initialize MAPI, Log on to MAPI, Open the Address Book...
    // Open GAL address book, Get content table(pHTable), 
    // Query phTable
    if (FAILED(hRes = HrQueryAllRows(pHTable, (LPSPropTagArray) &accCols, &pRestop, NULL, 0L, &pRows))) goto Cleanup; //this is where the error raised
```

I've seen Microsoft doc and search for several posts but cannot find a proper way to debug this.
So I'm wondering what situation might happened in the HrQueryAllRows method and how can I handle this error?

Comment: Does it work if you use a single RES_PROPERTY / PR_ANR instead of RES_AND?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko No. Still get the MAPI_E_TABLE_TOO_BIG error. Another weird behavior is that if I combine "s" or "x" with other valid string in one query, only the results of the valid strings will return (no error raised). Let say I choose "s" for the first string, "a" for the second string, and run the query, only the results of "a" return (have the same result as using "a" for query string alone)

Comment: The it is probably safe to assume that the GAL provider refuses to search if the search string is too short and it expects too many matches to be returned.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko sorry my bad! I didn't update the arguments of the HrQueryAllRows method before. Using single RES_PROPERTY doesn't work. Instead, it returns MAPI_E_INVALID_PARAMETER err. I've looked into this issue and found out the problem was the PR_ANR_W tag. If I change this tag into a specific tag(let say PR_DISPLAY_NAME_W), it works alone. So, why RES_PROPERTY with PR_ANR only work with RES_AND, not quite make sense to me. Thanks for the help!!